# Why does Alexa Shopping error when doing Buy Now?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

So I am doing an Alexa Shopping directive and I am getting back the following error:

```
"request": {
        "type": "SessionResumedRequest",
        "requestId": "xxxxxxxx",
        "timestamp": "2023-11-14T17:25:03Z",
        "locale": "en-GB",
        "cause": {
            "type": "ConnectionCompleted",
            "token": "PurchaseProductToken",
            "status": {
                "code": "200",
                "message": "SUCCESS:Successful."
            },
            "result": {
                "code": "AlexaShopping.RetryLaterError",
                "message": "Encountered an error when trying to process the request, please try again later."
            }
        }
    }
```

I am doing this while the skill is in test - does this cause the error???

Also this is my directive code:

```
let lAsin = "B08BPWRJ5D";
actionTask = {
        'type': 'Connections.StartConnection',
        'uri': 'connection://AMAZON.AddToShoppingCart/1',
        'input': {
          'products': [
            {
              'asin': lAsin
            }
          ]
        },
        'token': 'AddToShoppingCartToken'
      };
      return responseBuilder
        .addDirective(actionTask)
        .withShouldEndSession(undefined)
        .getResponse();
```

I'm sure that I was able to test this in test before without any error's so I'm not sure what has changed. I have followed the code correctly and used different ASINs and still the same result

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing this while the skill is in test - does this cause the error???

The `AlexaShopping.RetryLaterError` error you are receiving should not be affected by testing via the Alexa Developer Console Alexa simulator. This may have been due to a temporary Alexa Shopping issue. Is the issue ongoing?

If so, the issue may be related to your test account settings. For instance, the product(s) may not be available in your Amazon account marketplace. You can check your preferred marketplace on the Digital Payment Settings page on the Amazon website for your country. You can also find this in the Alexa app by navigating to More > Settings > General > About, where your marketplace is shown under Host Name. If you need to change this setting for testing purposes, you can follow the steps outlined here:
https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201248840